# Crear un usario de Bases de datos desde un procedimiento almacenado

Tags: mysql

He estado intentando crear un usuario de bases de datos con el grant create user desde un procedimiento alacenado en mysql, pero no lo he logrado alguna sugerencia? Gracias de ante mano

Comment: Bienvenido! Por favor, edita la pregunta y agrega el código que has intentando.

Comment: ¿Por qué no lo ha logrado?, ¿no puede crear el procedimiento almacenado?, ¿el procedimiento almacenado, al ejecutarlo, muestra algún error?, ¿puede publicar el código usado?. Una primera opción como sugerencia es investigar sobre sentencias preparadas, [13.5 Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html).